# How to conda install openAI gym on Linux - Package Conflicts

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, conda, openai-gym

I am trying to install the gym package in conda for Linux. I have created a virtual environment and am using the following command to try and install:

```
(gym_env) [user]$ conda install --name gym_env -c hcc gym
```

But am getting the following issue:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: /
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.                                                                                                        failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:



Package libgcc-ng conflicts for:
python=3.6 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.2.0|>=7.3.0']
Package libstdcxx-ng conflicts for:
python=3.6 -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.2.0|>=7.3.0']
Package xz conflicts for:
python=3.6 -> xz[version='>=5.2.3,<6.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0']
Package libffi conflicts for:
python=3.6 -> libffi[version='3.2.*|>=3.2.1,<4.0a0']
Package sqlite conflicts for:
python=3.6 -> sqlite[version='>=3.20.1,<4.0a0|>=3.22.0,<4.0a0|>=3.23.1,<4.0a0|>=3.24.0,<4.0a0|>=3.25.2,<4.0a0|>=3.26.0,<4.0a0|>=3.29.0,<4.0a0']
Package requests conflicts for:
gym -> requests[version='>=2.0']
Package pyglet conflicts for:
gym -> pyglet[version='>=1.2.0']
Package tk conflicts for:
python=3.6 -> tk[version='8.6.*|>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0']
Package openssl conflicts for:
python=3.6 -> openssl[version='1.0.*|1.0.*,>=1.0.2l,<1.0.3a|>=1.0.2m,<1.0.3a|>=1.0.2n,<1.0.3a|>=1.0.2o,<1.0.3a|>=1.0.2p,<1.0.3a|>=1.1.1a,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1c,<1.1.2a']
Package zlib conflicts for:
python=3.6 -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
Package ncurses conflicts for:
python=3.6 -> ncurses[version='6.0.*|>=6.0,<7.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0']
Package numpy conflicts for:
gym -> numpy[version='>=1.10.4']
Package six conflicts for:
gym -> six
Package pip conflicts for:
python=3.6 -> pip
Package readline conflicts for:
python=3.6 -> readline[version='7.*|>=7.0,<8.0a0']
Package scipy conflicts for:
gym -> scipy
```

I am finding it difficult to interpret this error so am not sure where to go from here to try and fix it.

I also tried installing the package at the same time as creating the environemt but there was the same issue.

**Python version - 3.6.9
conda version - 4.7.12**

Hopefully someone can help me!

Comment: Adding conda forge to the channels worked, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the `hcc` channel hosts the `gym` package, it has a requirement of `pyglet` which is not available on `hcc` or `defaults`. Try also including the `conda-forge` channel as well:

```
conda create -n gym_env -c hcc -c conda-forge python=3.6 gym
```

Note, that when creating an env for a specialized purpose, it is generally recommended to include the key packages at creation.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5):

The error means that the package has dependency requirements that conflict with one another. Given that you've tried to install this into a fresh environment with nothing else installed, this is something that the package maintainer needs to fix, and there is not much else you can do.

Alternatively, you can try `pip install gym` to install the package. Check out their [README on GitHub](https://github.com/openai/gym#installation) for more information. In case you're not aware, you can [use Pip in a conda environment](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/).

Comment: This is the way to do it. Make your conda env, and then do `pip install gym` inside it.

Answer (score 0):

https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/gym

conda install -c conda-forge gym